# Android - Google map api v2 & android 2.3.7

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I use Google map api v2 for my app abd run this app in my device (android 2.3.7). It ok when running direct to device but when i export app to a *.apk then install in this device, run the app, it only show white screen.....

Comment: "running direct" is using debug signature(stored in debug.keystore) ... if you "export" app from eclipse you are using release signature to sign app ... you did not register release signature in google console or release signature need different key in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create the release certificate.
To create release certificate :
    - After created the release keystore and signed the .APK. you can get the release certificate fingerprint.
    - open Terminal and type the command:
        keytool -list -v -keystore <your_keystore_name> -alias <your_alias_name>
        where:
            <your_keystore_name> is the path and name of the keystore, including the .keystore extension.
            <your_alias_name> is alias that you assigned to the certificate when you created it.

Now to register this release certificate in google console along with the debug certificate. 
And Use that key in manifest file.
```